# Is there an easy way to add parameters to a caret model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm using caret to train an xgboost model on an imbalanced dataset, and by default caret does not allow the specification of the `scale_pos_weight` parameter.

I was just wondering if there was an "easy" way of adding an extra parameter for the tuning, as the only way I can think of doing it is by copying the code for the `xgbTree` model and modifying it so that the parameter tuning can also include `scale_pos_weight`.

Comment: Have you looked in the online book for caret, https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html

Comment: you need to modify the model... or you write something to tune it manually...